# Who knew first that Tom Riddle was the Heir of Slytherin: Tom Riddle or Dumbledore?

Tags: harry-potter, voldemort, albus-dumbledore, slytherin

While watching *Harry Potter and the Half-Blood Prince* this morning, my son asked a lot of plot questions, and one of his inquiries about Tom Riddle stumped me. So, here I am, asking all you fine people for help!

**Who knew first that Tom Riddle was the Heir of Slytherin: Tom Riddle or Dumbledore?**

I would love to see a definitive canon answer to this question, if at all possible.

There were obviously different clues dropped over the years that pointed toward Tom Riddle being the Heir of Slytherin. A few examples:

- Tom Riddle disclosed he could speak with snakes to Dumbledore when Tom was eleven and did not yet know the implications of being a Parselmouth.
- Merope Gaunt's Slytherin lineage.
- The diary Horcrux and the Chamber of Secrets.
- The basilisk and Myrtle's death.

Is it established in canon -- in reference to the Heir of Slytherin, Dumbledore, and Tom Riddle -- who knew what, and when? **Who knew first that Tom Riddle was the Heir of Slytherin?**

As I already mentioned, I'm looking for an answer grounded in canon -- the books, interviews and/or quotes by J.K. Rowling, or Pottermore. Speculative answers within the spirit of canon are totally fine by me. I did search the site to ensure this question has not been asked already and I didn't find anything -- if this is a duplicate, vote accordingly :)

Comment: It seems pretty likely that Riddle knew first. Dumbledore had no reason to dig into Riddle’s family history until the opening of the Chamber, and the death of his Muggle father – he doesn’t seem to look into Voldemort’s path until Morfin’s imprisonment, towards the end of Riddle’s school career, by which time Riddle must already know of his Slytherin heritage.

Comment: I felt my answer was pretty comprehensive. Is there anything else you'd want me to address?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

First off, I'd like to dispute the nature of the question. Although Voldemort is the *youngest* known descendant of Salazar Slytherin it's pretty clear that other wizards have come from [the same lineage](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/13022/the-heir-of-slytherin-why-was-the-heir-tom-riddle?rq=1). As a matter of fact, Voldemort wasn't even the rightful heir. That dubious honour fell to Morfin Gaunt, Marvolo's *elder* son.

The whole "*Lord Voldemort : Heir of Slytherin*" seems to have been something that Voldemort concocted on his own, as part of his attempt to rationalise his mixed parentage and to construct a mythos around himself. **As such, Dumbledore couldn't have been the first to know that Riddle was styling himself thusly.**

---

That being said, it's reasonably certain that Voldemort was the first to learn about his true lineage as part of his research into his mother and father.

Dumbledore may have had his suspicions (due to the factors you've mentioned above) but it was definitely Tom Riddle who discovered his mother's name and learned of his family's connection to Salazar Slytherin;

> Finally he was forced to accept that his father had never set foot in
>   Hogwarts. I believe that it was then that he dropped the name for
>   ever, assumed the identity of Lord Voldemort, and began his
>   investigations into his previously despised mother’s family – the
>   woman whom, you will remember, he had thought could not be a witch if
>   she had succumbed to the shameful human weakness of death.
>
> **‘All he had to go upon was the single name “Marvolo”, which he knew
>   from those who ran the orphanage had been his mother’s father’s name.
>   Finally, after painstaking research through old books of wizarding
>   families, he discovered the existence of Slytherin’s surviving line.**
>   In the summer of his sixteenth year, he left the orphanage to which he
>   returned annually and set off to find his Gaunt relatives. - <sub><sup>HP and the Half Blood Prince</sup></sub>

Comment: I tend to agree with you Richard but, this makes me curious. Is there any prophesy that says to the effect that there would be a Heir of Slytherin?

Comment: Oops, I think I got it. ""Slytherin, according to the legend, sealed the Chamber of Secrets so that none would be able to open it until his own true heir arrived at the school. The heir alone would be able to unseal the Chamber of Secrets, unleash the horror within [...]" (CoS - pages 150-151 - US Hardcover)

Comment: @gelolopez - Interestingly, Ron also unseals the chamber. The whole "heir to Slytherin" thing seems to revolve around the fact that parseltongue is rare, appears to be genetic and is needed to open the chamber. Really, anyone could have done it.

Comment: Maybe by 'unseal' they meant open for the first time?

Comment: 'that Voldemort concocted on his own' Alternatively he was the 'last heir'. Other possibilities: there is some strange law at work that we don't know; that we don't know the entire line is also something that might (and might not) alter the way it's interpreted. Or perhaps it's something else entirely. Whether he was ever the only heir is of course different but I can then see how he meant he was ONE heir (and in his case the last)  - amongst others - of Slytherin and thus able to do Slytherin's work of purging the school of those unworthy of magic.

Comment: @Pryftan  -Sure, but given that Voldemort lied about his muggle heritage, it's just as likely (if not more so) that he's invented some cock and bull story about being the 'true heir' to one of the most notable dark wizards in history as a way of deflecting attention from his more dubious ancestors. He was certainly *a descendant*, but that's probably a distinction shared by hundreds.

Comment: @Valorum True. And I haven't any knowledge of the legal definition of 'heir' in any part of the world and most certainly not in Harry Potter. So perhaps then that thought of mine is not so valid; otoh it could be and if he was able to unleash the horror within it's implied then that he was. After all Harry was also a Parselmouth and he couldn't tell the Basilisk to leave him be, could he? Only Riddle had control over it so it seems to me that he was indeed the heir of Slytherin: **by Slytherin's definition at least!**

Comment: @Pryftan - My immediate assumption is that whenever a legal question comes up regarding HP, that we refer to the English legal tradition. Note, however that [other legal systems](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/60724/who-was-the-rightful-owner-of-the-sword-of-gryffindor) may apply.

Comment: @Valorum Oh I'd agree; don't get me wrong. I'm just saying that who knows with them? Maybe they have some additional ideas; they do after all see themselves superior. But my point of course was that I don't know the legal definition anywhere in the world. I think really what it comes down to is my point: in Slytherin's mind Riddle was one of the heirs or THE heir of Slytherin thus being able to purge the school of Muggle-borns.

Comment: @Pryftan Tom Riddle lies a lot he is almost always lying or being deceitful. We can't take Tom's words as being truthful. Tom implies that Harry can't control or even reason with the basilisk and Harry didn't try to.  According to the FBawtFT book, only parseltongues can control basilisks, Harry is a parseltongue, so Harry could have spoken to it. But he was about 13 and was being chased by a giant serpent, it didn't occur to him to try speaking to it.